# How do I allow outgoing connections to port 80 on a Remote Access VPN?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, remote-access, l2tp, port-80

I have setup a simple L2TP VPN by using the Remote Access role. This works fine, however outgoing connections to port 80 don't work. I can connect to the shares and RDP, however browsing the web is not possible.

How do I control this?

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the internet as a VPN client doesn't work? Or browsing the network behind the VPN as a VPN client doesn't work?

If it's the first issue, do you want VPN clients to access the internet through the VPN using the office network? Or do you want VPN clients to access the internet through their own network connection.  Why is there a distinction?

Well, the first option keeps all traffic encrypted/encapsulated, and all internet traffic goes through the office VPN.  The other option lets users access the office network using the VPN tunnel, while letting the users access the internet through their local network.  This is called split-tunneling.  If you want this, you need to have it configured on your VPN Server.  If you don't want it, you need to make sure it's not configured, and you need to make sure you set up a proper DNS forwarder and Default Gateway.

If you're not able to browse traffic on port 80 on your office network as a VPN client, you probably don't have firewall rules to allow it or you need to make sure you set up a proper DNS forwarder and Default Gateway.  An easy way to check is to try to access the resource by IP address instead of DNS name.

Comment: VPN clients can't browse the internet, local resources can be accessed, though.

Comment: By the way, I'd rather not use split-tunneling, as I don't want a VPN with an identity crisis.